# Cancelling a GraphQL Subscription

Tags: graphql

Is there a way to cancel a GraphQL subscription by sending an `unsubscribe` method?

For example if I send a subscription request as follows —

```
subscription votes($user: user) {
  count
}
```

How can I now cancel this request?

**NOTE:** I want to unsubscribe without closing the underlying connection.